# Aggregation in dynamic pivot table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 which has 5 million rows.

Table view is like this :

```
      CustomerID     ProdID    FavouriteProduct
          1              A              A
          1              A              A
          1              A              A
          1              B              A
          1              A              A
          1              A              A
          1              A              A
          1              B              A
          2              A              C
          2              AN             C
          2              G              C
          2              C              C
          2              C              C
          2              F              C
          2              D              C
          2              C              C
```

As you can see there are so many different products.

I already wrote a query for that :

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT 
    @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME(prodID)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ProdID FROM Table) AS Prods

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
           N'SELECT CustomerID, ' + @ColumnName + '
             FROM table 
             PIVOT(count(CustomerID) 
             FOR ProdID IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Normally, I expect `count(*)` or `Count(SubID)` would count the number of each products bought by each customer, but it doesn't. It says

> Invalid Column name CustomerID

instead.

Comment: there is another column in the table which says the quantity of products bought each time. but when i put sum (quantity) for aggregation. it returns 1 for all products which is not correct. @ t-clausen.dk

Comment: I think you used count instead of sum. Also I think this is what you need SELECT DISTINCT prodID FROM Table instead of DISTINCT City

Comment: the real table is completely different. i changed the names to customer and product to make it simpler. I'm sure i wrote sum(quantity) @ t-clausen.dk

Comment: I tried a new answer. I give up if that is not the issue

Comment: @Ariox66 Based on your sample data what do you want for the final result?  Also why not try writing the query via a static method (hard-coded values) first, before converting it to dynamic SQL?

Comment: @bluefeet i fount my mistake. in from ( i should have selected the column i want to count or sum ). anyway, do you have any idea how to store the data? this is a 5 million rows and 150 columns result and create view doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't count the CustomerId while selecting it, try this instead:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
       N'SELECT CustomerID, ' + @ColumnName + '
         FROM table 
         PIVOT(count(FavouriteProduct) 
         FOR ProdID IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
```

You need a column to count, and CustomerId is not allowed since you are selecting it. If FavouriteProduct fails, I suggest you fake a column or find another column.

Since you have more columns than described, I modified query. Try this instead:

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
   N'SELECT CustomerID, ' + @ColumnName + '
     FROM 
       (SELECT CustomerID, FavouriteProduct, ProdID FROM table) x
     PIVOT(count(FavouriteProduct) 
     FOR ProdID IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
```

Comment: can i count the dates they purchase that products?

Comment: Yes you can, but it will count all dates, not distinct dates, it will also count null values as 0.

Comment: i want it to count all products bought by each customer. so counting all dates would be Ok. but it returns just 1 though there are many customers who bought a product many times.

Comment: because it is pivot, it has a slightly different syntax